# Using the Send Log for Filter Criteria in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, filters

We have a requirement to not flow down a path if the subscriber has received a specific email (ex. Email1) in the past 7 days. We are using the Send Log, this contains the EMAILNAME and SENDDATE. The thought is this:

```
EMAILNAME Not Equal Email1 OR
(EMAILNAME Equal Email1 AND
SENDDATE Before today minus 7 days)
```

Our concern is if the subscriber received Email1 10 days ago and 1 day ago, will the 1 day ago send fail the filter even though the 10 day ago passes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been told by SFMC Support that the send 10 days ago will qualify the Subscriber to pass the filter, even though the 1 day ago send should fail them. Suggestion was to add a query activity to populate a Data Extension and use that as an exclusion in the filter.

Comment: Can you accept this answer to close the question if your question is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

1 day ago send will fail the filter because in the send log the recent entries are on the top, so when it will start checking, the 1 day before log will come first and it wont allow to flow down the path

Comment: That is my thought as well, but it doesn't seem to be working that way.